# Projection onto locally constant function

Tags: nt.number-theory, automorphic-forms, adeles

I am asking a question which looks very elementary to experts.

Let $F$ be a number field and $\mathbb{A}_F$ its adele ring. Let $\omega$ be a unitary central character of $GL_2(\mathbb{A}_F)$,

$X_{GL_2}=GL_2(F) \backslash GL_2(\mathbb{A}_F)$, and

$C^{\infty}_{\omega}(X_{GL_2})=\{f:X_{GL_2} \to \mathbb{C} \ | \ f(zg)=\omega(z)f(g) \text{ for $z\in$ center of $GL_2$ } \text{ and } \ g\mapsto f(xg) \text { is } C^{\infty}(F_{\infty}) \text{ for each } x\in X_{GL_2}\}$.

Define a projection map $P:C^{\infty}_{\omega}(X_{GL_2})\to C^{\infty}_{\omega}(X_{GL_2})$ by 
$$Pf(x):=\int_{h \in SL_2(F)\backslash SL_2(\mathbb{A}_F)}f(hx)\,dh.$$
Then how can we prove 
$$Pf(x)=\sum_{\chi^2=\omega} \chi(x) \cdot \left(\int_{PGL_2(F)\backslash PGL_2(\mathbb{A}_F)} f(y)\overline{\chi(y)}\,dy\right)?$$

Here, $\chi$ is a unitary character of $\mathbb{A}_F^{\times}/F^{\times}$, and $\chi^2=\omega$ if we think of $\chi$ as a character of $X_{GL_2}$ via $\chi(g)=\chi(\det g)$ for $g\in GL_2(\mathbb{A}_F)$.

Any comments will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is clear from the definition and right-invariance of the measure $dh$ that $Pf$ is left-invariant under $SL_2(\mathbb{A}_F)$. As Paul Garrett kindly explained, $Pf$ is also left-invariant under $GL_2(F)$, because $f$ is left-invariant under $GL_2(F)$ and $GL_2(F)$ normalizes the coset space $SL_2(F)\backslash SL_2(\mathbb{A}_F)$. As a result, for any $g\in GL_2(\mathbb{A}_F)$, we have
$$ Pf(g)=Pf\left(g\begin{pmatrix}\det g^{-1}&\\&1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}\det g&\\&1\end{pmatrix}\right)=Pf\left(\begin{pmatrix}\det g&\\&1\end{pmatrix}\right).$$
This motivates the definition
$$\widetilde{Pf}(a):=Pf\left(\begin{pmatrix}a&\\&1\end{pmatrix}\right),\qquad a\in\mathbb{A}_F^\times.$$
The function $\widetilde{Pf}$ is clearly invariant under $F^\times$. Moreover, it satisfies the identity
$$\tag{$\ast$}\widetilde{Pf}(ab^2)=\omega(b)\widetilde{Pf}(a),\qquad a,b\in\mathbb{A}_F^\times,$$
since
$$Pf\left(\begin{pmatrix}ab^2&\\&1\end{pmatrix}\right)=Pf\left(\begin{pmatrix}b&\\&b\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}a&\\&1\end{pmatrix}\right)=\omega(b)\,Pf\left(\begin{pmatrix}a&\\&1\end{pmatrix}\right).$$
Now let us fix a decomposition $\mathbb{A}_F^\times=\mathbb{R}_{>0}\times \mathbb{A}_F^1$ and focus on the compact quotient $\mathbb{A}_F^1/F^\times$. We have a spectral decomposition
$$ \widetilde{Pf}(a)=\sum_\chi c_\chi \chi(a),\qquad a\in\mathbb{A}_F^1,$$
where $\chi$ runs through the (discrete set of) characters of $\mathbb{A}_F^1/F^\times$. Then ($\ast$) yields, by the uniqueness of the spectral coefficients, that $c_\chi\chi^2(b)=c_\chi\omega(b)$ holds for any $b\in\mathbb{A}_F^1$. That is, $c_\chi=0$ unless $\chi^2=\omega$ on $\mathbb{A}_F^1$. Any such $\chi$ extends uniquely to a character of $\mathbb{A}_F^\times/F^\times$ maintaining the property $\chi^2=\omega$, and one can verify, using ($\ast$) and existence of square-roots in $\mathbb{R}_{>0}$, that these extended idele class characters satisfy
$$ \widetilde{Pf}(a)=\sum_{\chi^2=\omega} c_\chi \chi(a),\qquad a\in\mathbb{A}_F^\times.$$
The coefficients $c_\chi$ can be evaluated by the orthogonality of characters,
\begin{align*} c_\chi&=\int_{\mathbb{A}_F^1/F^\times}\widetilde{Pf}(a)\,\overline{\chi(a)}\,da\\
&=\int_{\mathbb{A}_F^1/F^\times}\int_{h \in SL_2(F)\backslash SL_2(\mathbb{A}_F)}f\left(h\begin{pmatrix}a&\\&1\end{pmatrix}\right)\overline{\chi(a)}\,dh\,da\\
&=\int_{GL_2(F)\backslash GL_2^{(1)}(\mathbb{A}_F)}f(g)\,\overline{\chi(\det g)}\,dg,
\end{align*}
where $GL_2^{(1)}(\mathbb{A}_F)$ denotes the subgroup of adelic matrices whose determinant lies in $\mathbb{A}_F^1$. The result is immediate from here, since $f(g)\,\overline{\chi(\det g)}$ as a function on $GL_2(\mathbb{A}_F)$ is invariant under the center (recalling that $\chi^2=\omega$).

Comment: GH from MO, Thank you for great answer. It helped me a lot. 
But there are two points I did not understand well.

1. You wrote "$$ \widetilde{Pf}(a)=\sum_\chi c_\chi \chi(a),\qquad a\in\mathbb{A}_F^1,$$
where $\chi$ runs through the (discrete set of) characters of $\mathbb{A}_F^1/F^\times$."

It looks that it comes from something like Fourier transfor on compact group. But since I don't know much about this, would recommend a book or paper which deals this material?

Comment: 2. I am wondering if $GL_2^{(1)}(\mathbb{A}_F)/Z(\mathbb{A}_F)$ is isomorphic to $PGL_2(\mathbb{A}_F)$?
Because it looks that you are claiming the last integral over $GL_2$ you wrote is equal to the integral over $PGL_2$.

Would you please shed me a light on these two points?

I am always thank you very much!

Comment: @Monty: For the harmonic analysis used here, I recommend Weil: Basic number theory and Ramakrishnan-Valenza: Fourier analysis on number fields. Also, the group $GL_2^{(1)}(\mathbb{A}_F)/Z^{(1)}(\mathbb{A}_F)$ is isomorphic to $PGL_2(\mathbb{A}_F)$. To see this, consider the natural projection $GL_2(\mathbb{A}_F)\to PGL_2(\mathbb{A}_F)$, and restrict it to $GL_2^{(1)}(\mathbb{A}_F)$. This restriction is surjective, and its kernel is $Z^{(1)}(\mathbb{A}_F)$, done.

Comment: Thank you again for your reply! By your precious comment, I took a look on Ramakrishnan's book and found that the Fourier inversion formula is what you applied. But I have still three questions and would like to ask them to you if you don't mind.

To apply fourier inversion formula, the function $\widetilde{Pf}$ should be of positive type according to Thm 3.9. But I can't check it. How did you check it? Or is there alternative condition to apply Fourier inversion formula, like smoothness?

Comment: Secondly, you wrote $\chi:\mathbb{A^{1}_F}/F^{\times} \to \mathbb{C}^{\times}$ can be uniquely lifted to the character of $\mathbb{A_F}^{\times}/F^{\times}$ satisfying $$ \widetilde{Pf}(a)=\sum_\chi c_\chi \chi(a),\qquad a\in\mathbb{A}_F^{\times}$$.

I am wondering that how one can uniquely extend it to character of $\mathbb{A_F}^{\times}/F^{\times}$?

Comment: Thirdly, I am wondering if the discrete decomposition of $\widetilde{Pf}$ is the very reason you restricted the domain of it to $\mathbb{A^{1}_F}/F^{\times}$ rather than $\mathbb{A_F^{\times}}/F^{\times}$.

But how about applying FI directly to original $\widetilde{Pf}$ and we get integral decomposition like $\widetilde{Pf}(x)=\int_{\chi \in \widehat{\mathbb{A}_{F^{\times}}/F^{\times}}} c_{\chi} \chi(x) d\chi$ and still we get $c_{\chi}=0$ if $\chi^2 \ne \omega$.

I am very sorry for bothering you. But I want to have a complete understanding on your answer not making your effort void!

Comment: The Fourier inversion works more generally than for functions of positive type. See Thm 3.26 and the previous page in the book. In particular, any continuous function on a compact abelian group is an infinite linear combination of characters (that converges everywhere), and for smooth functions the coefficients decay rapidly. And yes, I chose to work with $\mathbb{A}_F^1/F^\times$ so that I can deal with a compact group and don't have to talk about integrals on the Fourier side, which in the end boil down to a discrete sum anyways (by the proof I gave). I will continue in the next comment.

Comment: To your remaining question: we have fixed a decomposition $\mathbb{A}_F^\times=\mathbb{R}_{>0}\times \mathbb{A}_F^1$, so any character $\lambda$ of this group decomposes as $|\cdot|^{it}$ times the restriction of $\lambda$ to $\mathbb{A}_F^1$, where the archimedean parameter $t\in\mathbb{R}$ is uniquely determined by $\lambda$. So $\chi^2=\omega$ on $\mathbb{A}_F^\times$ means that $\chi^2=\omega$ on $\mathbb{A}_F^1$ and the archimedean parameter of $\chi$ is half of the archimedean parameter of $\omega$. As real numbers can be halved uniquely, my claim follows.

Comment: Let me also clarify what I meant by "$\chi$ can be extended to a character of $\mathbb{A}_F^\times/F^\times$ maintaining the property $\chi^2=\omega$". I meant that, given a character $\chi_1$ of $\mathbb{A}_F^1/F^\times$ such that $\chi_1^2=\omega^2$ holds on $\mathbb{A}_F^1/F^\times$, there is a unique character $\chi$ of $\mathbb{A}_F^\times/F^\times$ such that $\chi^2=\omega^2$ and the restriction of $\chi$ to $\mathbb{A}_F^1/F^\times$ is $\chi_1$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind answer. I learned much from comments. Thm 3.26 and the previous page of the Rama's book seems to allow the scope of functions, which are being applicable of F.I formula, from positive definite to $L^2$ functions and I knew why Bruhat-Schwarts function appeared in Tate thesis. So it remains to check that $\widetilde{Pf}$ is in $L^2(\mathbb{A}_F^{\times}/F^{\times})$ that looks not so obvious though. But I really thank you again!^^

Comment: @Monty: $\widetilde{Pf}$ does not lie in $L^2(\mathbb{A}_F^{\times}/F^{\times})$, because its absolute value is invariant under the action of the non-compact factor $\mathbb{R}_{>0}$ by ($\ast$). However, the restriction of $\widetilde{Pf}$ to the compact subgroup $\mathbb{A}_F^1/F^{\times}$ does lie in $L^2(\mathbb{A}_F^1/F^{\times})$, and this is all you need. Once you have the spectral decomposition of this restriction, it extends to $\mathbb{A}_F^{\times}/F^{\times}$ as required. This follows from ($\ast$) and my earlier comments. Note the discrete nature of your problem and the result.

Comment: Great! I completely understand your answer! We cannot directly apply F.I formula to $\widetilde{Pf}$, but possible to its restriction on $\mathbb{A}^1_F/F^{\times}$. So in turn, we get $$ \widetilde{Pf}=\sum_{\chi^2=\omega} c_\chi \chi$$ for almost everywhere $\mathbb{A}^1_F$. (Because they are same only in the $L^2$-sense.) But the continuity of $\widetilde{Pf}$ and $\chi$ makes them hold for all $a\in \mathbb{A}^1_F$. Another key point is that character of $\mathbb{A}_F^{\times}/F^{\times}$ is almost uniquely determined by its restriction to $\mathbb{A}^1_F/F^{\times}$.

Comment: That's what I understand from your replies. Is it right? Thank you for illumination on my numerous stupid questions. I learned much from your answers. Thank you again!

Comment: @Monty: You understand it right. Note that, thanks to ($\ast$), we know precisely how $\widetilde{Pf}$ transforms under (the embedded copy of) $\mathbb{R}_{>0}$. So if we know how $\widetilde{Pf}$ decomposes over $\mathbb{A}_F^1/F^\times$, we also know how it decomposes over $\mathbb{A}_F^\times/F^\times$. The effect of this transformation is exactly that each solution of $\chi^2=\omega$ over $\mathbb{A}_F^1/F^\times$ gets lifted to a solution of  $\chi^2=\omega$ over $\mathbb{A}_F^\times/F^\times$.

Comment: Your comment convinced what I have thought. Thank you very much!